# Parse::ABNF perl usage

Tags: perl, parsing, sip, cpan, abnf

I need to parse the SIP headers ([grammar](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/sip/SIPgrammar.html#accept) in ABNF format) and verify if my Header strings are ok or not.

(Example: check strings like "Accept: application/sdp,application/3gpp-imp+xml" to provide testcase pass/fail).

Currently I am trying to use perl [Parse::ABNF](http://search.cpan.org/~bjoern/Parse-ABNF-0.05/lib/Parse/ABNF.pm).  Now I am not able to understand the sample usage in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.   I am still facing difficulty in resolving my problem.  Request to see my problem below and provide pointers to solution.

Answer (score 1):

My `Parse::ABNF` module reads ABNF grammars and gives you access to the rules in the grammar. It tells you things like "The `floating-point-number` rule references the `digit` rule", but it does not generate a parser for floating point numbers. You can use the module to convert a proper ABNF grammar into a format that can be used by a parser generator like `Parse::RecDescent` or `Marpa2`. An example script for such a conversion is included in the distribution as [`eg/abnf2xlx.pl`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BJOERN/Parse-ABNF-0.10/eg/abnf2xlx.pl). Note however that the grammar on the page you link to is not quite the standards-compliant format expected by `Parse::ABNF`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this module in this way:

```
  use Parse::ABNF;
  use Test::More;
  use Data::Dumper;
  my $parser = Parse::ABNF->new;
  my $rules = $parser->parse($sip_message);
  ok(defined $rules,'The SIP messgae is parseable') or diag(Dumper($sip_message));
```

The easier way for parsing just the header:

```
  use Test::More;
  use Data::Dumper;
  ok($sip_message =~ m!Accept: application/sdp,application/3gpp-imp+xml!,'The SIP header looks found') or diag(Dumper($sip_message));
```